# FetchXML reports in MSCRM Online do not work for more than 250. It throws generic error message

Tags: fetchxml

While running the FetchXML reports from BIDS(Business Intelligence Development Studio), all of them work fine with all filters applied.

But, when the same report is  deployed to MSCRM Online, they throw a generic error message(message: error occurred, contact administrator). These deployed reports work fine when only few values are selected for specific filters(in online deployment). But they fail when all values are selected in filter. For ex, Account Performance Dashboard report has this issue. When we select Account filter up to 250 with all Finplan groups selected, it is working fine whereas it fails for more than 300+ accounts.

Conceptually whatever executes successfully in BIDS should execute successfully when deployed also. But this is not happening. Can I simply go to Microsoft Connect and raise bug?  Or is there any step which I am missing?

Also the same query works fine in Advanced find, but it throws error in report(having selection more than 250) which works fine in BIDS.

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself!

CRM online has restrictions and limits. Refer the below links. We cannot design huge query reports for MSCRM Online 2011

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12601.crm-2011-timeouts-and-limits.aspx

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/rdt/archive/2012/08/31/microsoft-crm-2011-timeouts-and-limits.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334634.aspx

In this document you will find general information about limits which could be put on place on a CRM Environment, I hope you will find this useful:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27139